# How to open a file with write access on OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, chmod

I am trying to open `private/etc/php.ini.default` file to add `detect_unicode = Off`. But after opening above file with this command `vim php.ini.default`, it only opens this file as readonly. How can I open this file as writable? I need to add above line of code because I want to install composer and facing some problems and cannot install it without adding above line of code.

Comment: You can force write with `:w!` or if you don't have permissions you can edit the file with `sudo vim`. This is a weird question.

Comment: Not weird, just off-topic.

Comment: it's weird because vim would give you one of two error messages, "file is readonly, add ! to write" or "permission denied", both of which are googlable, and both are pretty obvious as to what to do. why waste your time asking us?

Comment: I am with @AndyRay on this one mostly because if I read "file is readonly, add ! to write," I add '!' to write.

Comment: I googled and found this. Irony. + 2000 views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your own risk, 
You can use sudo to open and change it.
If you need to change it's permission you can use

```
chmod u+w <filewithpath>
```